# MFC domodal() issue for two threads

Tags: mfc

My application uses ZModem protocol for communication.

From main thread, I am created second thread for progess bar. So, main thread is working on communication and second thread is for extra work. They are communicated through global variable.

If they are on same thread then main windows communication will be blocked.
Now, because of two thread they cannot uses `DoModal()` with each other.
What can i do for `DoModal()` this two thread or there is any option for doing it on one thread but communicating same way?

Comment: Start to take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thdxkfx9.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Control all windows from the main thread. Use a second thread for the communication operations.

Comment: How? Any another option for doing this?

Comment: You must keep the GUI thread flowing, and serial I/O blocks, so no, no other option. There are several relevant tutorials here: http://www.flounder.com/mvp_tips.htm#hreads and Processes series